# Matplotlib 3D scatter autoscale issue

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Python 2.7, matplotlib 1.5.1, Win 7, x64

I am trying to plot the shortest distances between a node & its geometrical nearest neighbour (ie not its nearest connected neighbour) in a graph using Dijkstra's algorithm.

The algorithm is working fine but when it comes to plotting, matplotlib's scaling freaks out when I plot certain nodes.

Code snippet:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# Find the paths between a given node & its nearest neighbours

def plotPath(pathStart, pathEnd, pointCol='b'):

    shortPath = graph.dijkstra(pathStart, pathEnd) # this calculates the shortest path

    pathNodesIdx = [i-1 for i in shortPath] # Algorithm returns 1 indexed whilst Python uses 0 indexed
    pathCoords = L3.nodes[pathNodesIdx, 1:4] # retrieves the coordinate for the nodes on the path

    ax.scatter(pathCoords[1:-1,0], pathCoords[1:-1,1], pathCoords[1:-1,2], s=240, c=pointCol, marker='o')
    startNode = pathCoords[0]
    endNode = pathCoords[-1]
    ax.scatter(startNode[0], startNode[1], startNode[2], s=240, c='g', marker='o')
    ax.scatter(endNode[0], endNode[1], endNode[2], s=240, c='r', marker='o')
    for node in pathCoords[1:]:
        ax.plot([startNode[0], node[0]], [startNode[1], node[1]], [startNode[2], node[2]], color=pointCol, linewidth=2.0)
        startNode = node

    return pathCoords


pointCol = 'b'
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

pathStart = 1 # given node
graph=Graph(L3.trabGraph) # L3.trabGraph is list conataining the edge/node/cost information for the graph

# Return indices for nearest neighbours
nearest = [i+1 for i in L3.nodeNeighbours(pathStart, numNeighs=6, method='brute')[1:]]
```

For example I just plot the path to the 2nd nearest neighbour using `plotPath(1, nearest[2])` I get:

[image]

But if I add the other nearest neighbours using,

```
p0 = plotPath(1, nearest[0])
p1 = plotPath(1, nearest[1])
p2 = plotPath(1, nearest[2])
p3 = plotPath(1, nearest[3])
p4 = plotPath(1, nearest[4])
```

I get:

[image]

For reference the coordinates of the nodes for each case:

```
p0 = array([[ 1.094,  1.76 ,  1.125],
       [ 1.188,  1.75 ,  1.104]])

p1 = array([[ 1.094,  1.76 ,  1.125],
       [ 1.104,  1.875,  1.094]])

p2 = array([[ 1.094,  1.76 ,  1.125],
       [ 1.188,  1.75 ,  1.104],
       [ 1.188,  1.688,  1.094]])

p3 = array([[ 1.094,  1.76 ,  1.125],
       [ 1.198,  1.76 ,  1.198]])

p4 = array([[ 1.094,  1.76 ,  1.125],
       [ 1.198,  1.76 ,  1.198],
       [ 1.188,  1.708,  1.198]])
```

For the life of me I dont see why matplotlib does this? Anybody know?

I have left out the implementations of the Dijkstra algorithm (from Rosetta code FYI) & the creation of the graph for the sake of brevity & the fact that I'm not at liberty to share the graph information.

Comment: Can you tell us what exactly matplotlib does that you don't like/expect here and how you would the result like to look? Without knowing what you're trying to achieve nobody can help you. Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) helps.

Comment: The 2 images in the post contain the same data. In the first image you can see that the graph has auto-scaled to fit the size of the canvas to the data. In the 2nd image an extra 7 points are added to the plot but the auto-scale has increased the size of the canvas to such an extent that the points are now all bunched up into the corner. As can be seen from the lists of points at the end of the post, all the points only occupy a very small sub-section of the newly auto-scaled canvas.

Comment: Yes, true. But what exactly is the problem?

Comment: errr that is the problem

Comment: You can use the right mouse button to zoom in and out of your plot. Or you can set the axis limits via `ax.set_xlim([x, y])`.

Comment: The right mouse button wasnt doing anything but the set limits has done the trick. I couldnt find that in the docs for some reason. If you want to put that down as an answer I accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the question here really is "How do I set the limits of a 3d plot in matplotlib?" then the answer would be:

Just as you do in the 2d case:

```
ax.set_xlim([xmin, xmax])
ax.set_ylim([ymin, ymax])
ax.set_zlim([zmin, zmax])
```

Finding the values of min and max for respective cases might of course be automated.